# I want my object to fall when the player is near it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want my objects to fall when the player got to that scene . My game have a long map and I want them not to fall when I start the game .There is any code for player detection in the view? for the objects to fall?

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FallDown : MonoBehaviour
{
       public float fallSpeed = 8.0f;

    //Variables for starting position and length until reset
    private Vector3 _startingPos;
    public float FallDistance = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        // Save starting position
        _startingPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        // If the object has fallen longer than 
        // Starting height + FallDistance from its start position
        if (transform.position.y > _startingPos.y + FallDistance)
        {
            transform.position = _startingPos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. I'd suggest you looking into distance calculation between the player and the point where the falling object would land. Another approach would be having an "Event" that activates the falling object's movement (there are a lot of options: colliders f.e.). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing this behavior using Colliders?

To do it so, all you've got to do is add both a Collider Component and a RigidBody to your player and to the falling objects.

Once you've added them and configured their parameters, you can check the collision by using the method ***OnColissionEnter***. This method will be triggered every time that a collision is detected by the GameObject that is holding the script. In your case, the falling objects should hold it.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    //MAKE THE OBJECTS FALL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above is correct, Colliders might not be what you want to implement in this case. Colliders are used to, well, detect collisions, while you want the objects to fall when the player is at a specific distance from them. For this, I'd suggest adding a reference to the player GameObject first:

```
private GameObject playerRef;
```

And in the Start function find the player:

```
playerRef = GameObject.Find("yourPlayerGameObjectNameHere");
```

Get the GameObjects that you want to fall either by finding them, like above, or by passing a public reference to them through the inspector. Afterwards, you can use Vector3.distance between each GameObject and the player, like so:

```
if( Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, fallingObject.transform.position) < yourDistanceHere ){
    // Make the object fall
}
```